# TreePanel: why do I have to use Ext.crete for initializing store?

Tags: extjs, treepanel

On tree panel definition I would like to write (as I usually do with grid panels):

```
store: 'MyStore'
```

But it works only with

```
store: Ext.create('MyStore')
```

In the first case I have an error on missing store. Only the second option seems working. 
This gives me many troubles in a MVC design and I would like to avoid.
My question is: are there any way to set store as in the first option? It looks strange because for grid panel this store assignment works properly.

Here the full code:

```
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/packages/ext-theme-classic/build/resources/ext-theme-classic-all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function () {

            try {

                //define model
                Ext.define('MyDataModel', {
                    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

                    fields: [
                        { name: 'nodename', mapping: 'nodename' }
                    ],

                });

                //define store
                Ext.define('MyStore', {
                    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

                    storeId: 'idStoreLryManager',
                    model: 'MyDataModel',

                    root: {
                        nodename: 'myRoot',
                        expanded: true
                    },

                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url: 'test_lrymgr.json',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root: 'data',
                            metaProperty: 'metadata',
                            totalProperty: 'metadata.totalCount',
                            successProperty: 'metadata.success',
                            messageProperty: 'metadata.msg'
                        },
                    }
                });

                //define tree panel
                Ext.define('MyTreePanel', {
                    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
                    alias: 'widget.myTreePanel',

                    store: Ext.create('MyStore'),

                    rootVisible: true,

                    columns: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'treecolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'nodename',
                            sortable: false,
                            flex: 2,
                            header: ''
                        }
                    ]
                });


                //create tree view
                Ext.createWidget('window', {
                    title: 'test',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    autoShow: true,
                    height: 360,
                    width: 200,
                    items: {
                        xtype: 'myTreePanel',
                        border: false
                    }
                });

            }
            catch (ex) {
                Ext.Msg.alert("", ex)
            }
        });



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here the json:

```
{   
    "data": [   
        {
            "nodename": "AAA",
            "isvisible": true,
            "expanded": false,
            "leaf": false,
            "data": [
                {
                    "nodename": "BBB.1",
                    "isvisible": true,
                    "expanded": false,
                    "leaf": true
                },              
                {
                    "nodename": "BBB.2",
                    "isvisible": false,
                    "expanded": false,
                    "leaf": true
                }
            ]          
        },
        {
            "nodename": "BBB",
            "isvisible": true,
            "expanded": false,
            "leaf": true
        }           
    ],
    "metadata": { "success":true, "msg":"", "totalCount":1, "totalPages":1, "prevLink":"", "nextLink":""}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use MVC and you list the store in `stores:[]` array of Application or a Controller, then Ext creates the store for you and registers it in `StoreManager`. Then you can use string with storeId in your tree panel.

For example:

```
// in Application.js
stores:['MyStore']

// in tree config
store:'MyStore'
```

works.

However, the above code bypasses the MVC so that you have to create the store explicitly with `Ext.create`

Comment: Great! Your answer helped me. In my controller I've listed my store, but with a full path <app name>.store.<store name>. Now I've listed with only store name (as in your answer) and it works. What happens is that exjs did not give me any feedback on this wrong name, and that's what confused me. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry if I don't score your answer, but I can't: I'm new here and my reputation is still too low. Regards :) .